# why this command is not returning the alias?

Tags: powershell

So I need to return the alias of ipconfig.exe but when I look for ipconfig I don't get any result. It's like this command is not working with the camp at the right of the arrow, so how is the correct command to look what is the alias of ipconfig?
[image]

Comment: As far as I know does ipconfig not have an alias by default. With `Get-Alias | Get-Member` you can see all possible properties. I'd try my luck with `Definition` or `ResolvedCommand`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To look up an alias **by its *name*** or name *[wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) pattern*, use `Get-Alias -Name`:

```sh
# Note: The (first) positional argument implies -Name
Get-Alias *config*
```

To look up an alias **by its *definition*** (wildcard patterns also accepted), use the `-Definition` parameter:

```sh
Get-Alias -Definition *config*
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

It's natural to think that, given that `Get-Alias`'s *for-display* output formatting reports *both* the alias name *and* its definition in its `Name` *display column* (separated with `->`), that the underlying `.Name` *property* of the underlying [`System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo) type also contains that information.

However, **the `Name` *display column* is an artifact of the [*formatting data*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) associated with the output type, which provides a concise representation of aliases that *combines* two of the underlying type's properties**, namely the `.Name` property, which contains the alias' name *only*, and the separate `.Definition` property, containing the alias' definition (only), which is the one that  `Get-Alias`'s `-Definition` parameter acts on.

As [Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) suggests, you can pipe the output from `Get-Alias` to the [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) cmdlet in order to reflect on the output type (to see its properties and methods and, if applicable, events).

In other words: Your original approach would have worked if you had targeted the `.Definition` property in your [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call instead - but using the `-Definition` parameter is both more concise and more efficient:

```sh
# Less efficient equivalent of:
#   Get-Alias -Definition *config*
Get-Alias | Where-Object Definition -match config
```

Comment: The key was -Definition argument, I didn't know what the camp next to -> was named, I was trying looking in the output then trying to do a "grep" like in linux. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped, @AndresPasquel; my pleasure; I now see where your confusion came from - please see my update.